# Is "Tax return" right term even if I must pay more tax at the procedure?

Tags: word-usage

I must file a tax return for this year.

But I feel it's a bit strange to use a word "return" when I must pay the tax.
(Because income tax is not deducted in advance, I must pay it end of the fiscal year.)

Is there a expression like "file a tax pay"?

Comment: The "return" part refers to the form that you will send to the tax agency. Payment is a different matter, and can be described like any other monetary transaction (that is paying your taxes due, or getting a refund).

Comment: In case it's not clear, this means that you have to say two separate things: "I have to file a tax return this year" and "I will have to pay income tax (when I file)."

Answer (score 2):

'*Return*' as a noun has a specific use in legal and financial terminology. Websters dictionary defines these as:

> - the delivery of a legal order (such as a writ) to the proper officer or court
> - an account or formal report

A 'tax return' does not refer to your money, and it does not mean money that is 'returned' to you. A 'tax return' is the name of the official document that you file with the taxation office in order for them to process your tax and charge or rebate you accordingly.